# multer req.body showing empty always

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am learning nodejs and express, i was trying to do file upload below is my code

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT||3000;
const path = require('path');
const fs= require('fs');
const xlsx = require('node-xlsx');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser')

const storage=multer.diskStorage({
  destination:'./public/uploads',
  filename:function(req,file,cb){
    cb(null,file.fieldname+'-'+Date.now()+path.extname(file.originalname))
  }
})

const upload=multer({
  storage:storage
})


app.set('port',port);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static('./public'));

app.post('/uploadTest', upload.single('myImage'),function (req, res, next) {
setTimeout(function(){

  console.log(req.files);
  console.log(req.body);// {"someParam": "someValue"}
  res.send(req.body);


}, 3000);


  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})

var server=app.listen(app.get('port'),(req,res)=>{
  console.log(`server started at port ${app.get('port')}`)
});
```

and below is my HTML

```
<form action="/uploadTest" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myImage"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add File"/>
</form>
```

so my issue is `console.log(req.body);// {"someParam": "someValue"}` this is always showing empty object i google alot but didnt able to make it working

this is the output i am getting

```
[ { fieldname: 'myImage',
    originalname: 'SampleXLSFile_19kb.xls',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    destination: './public/uploads',
    filename: 'myImage-1534000938255.xls',
    path: 'public\\uploads\\myImage-1534000938255.xls',
    size: 19456 } ]
{}
```

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `req.body` will hold any text fields from your form if any are there, which in this case there aren't any. You don't specifically mention what you want to do with the file, but you can see that your file upload was successful when you log the `req.files` array. It has your file object there. You should be able to perform operations on that file either using the path or the `buffer` property of the object which contains a buffer of the entire file.

Comment: i was trying to upload excel and read data and insert into mongodb

Comment: When you say "read data", are you trying to transform it at all? I see you've required the node xlxs library as well, we're you trying to parse and convert the spreadsheet into a different format before saving? You'll probably need to ask another question on how to do that if you're having trouble with it,but for getting access to the file itself, you should use the `req.file` object which contains the path to the file and buffer, and either can be used to read the file into memory.

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js change this :

```
const upload=multer({
  dest:'./public/uploads'
})
```

and try,